# Add data from multiple scrapers to a csv file with same headers

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I have two scrapers that provides output in the same format: Link, Description. I can get them both to output that in a CSV file. However I can't get it to output the data in the same CSV file, it only outputs the data from one of the scrapers.

I have tried to use the 'a' to append the file when I export the data, but it only reflects the data from the first scraper.

**My Question Is**

*How can I add data to the same CSV file from multiple scrapers in a way so it simply adds the data in the new row?*

Example of the structure I want in the CSV:

```
HEADER: [Link, Description] 
ROW 1: [Link from scraper 1, Description from Scraper 1]
ROW 2: [Link from scraper 1, Description from Scraper 1]
ROW 3: [Link from scraper 2, Description from Scraper 2]
```

**Code for scraper 1**

```
import csv ; import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open('DeloitteImplementTest.csv','a')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["job_link", "job_desc"])

res = requests.get("http://deloittedk.easycruit.com/?_sp=136ecff9b65625bf.1504382903200&icid=top_").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
        item_link = link.get("href").strip()
        item_text = link.text.replace("View Position","").encode('utf-8').strip()
        writer.writerow([item_link, item_text])
        print(item_link, item_text)
```

**Code for scraper 2**

```
import csv ; import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open('DeloitteImplementTest.csv','a')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["job_link", "job_desc"])

res = requests.get("http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/6257").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")

for li in soup.find('ul', class_='list-articles list').find_all('li'):
    level = li.find_all('dd', {'class': 'author'})[1].get_text()
    if "Graduate" in level:
        links = li.find_all(href=True)
        for link in links:
            if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
                item_link = link.get("href").strip()
                item_text = link.text.replace("View Position","").encode('utf-8').strip()
                writer.writerow([item_link, item_text])
                print(item_link, item_text)
```

**Edited code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

class createCSV:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        try:
            self.csvFile = open(filename,'ab')
            headers = ['Link','Description']
            self.writer = csv.DictWriter(self.csvFile, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=headers)

            if os.stat(filename).st_size == 0:  # write header only once
                self.writer.writeheader()       
        except Exception, error:
            print error

    def write_row(self,link,desc):
        self.writer.writerow({'Link':link, 'Description':desc})

    def __del__(self):
        self.csvFile.close()

res = requests.get("http://deloittedk.easycruit.com/?_sp=136ecff9b65625bf.1504382903200&icid=top_").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")

# here we create the "test.csv" which 
# we will use to append values to
outfile = createCSV('test10.csv')

for link in links:
        item_link = link.get("href").strip()
        item_text = link.text.replace("View Position","").encode('utf-8').strip()
        # append values to "test.csv"
        outfile.write_row(item_link, item_text)

# Remember that for the second scraper to write on the same .csv file 
# as the first one, you need to use the same 'createCSV' object - which 
# in this case is the "outfile".


res = requests.get("http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/6257").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")

for li in soup.find('ul', class_='list-articles list').find_all('li'):
    level = li.find_all('dd', {'class': 'author'})[1].get_text()
    if "Graduate" in level:
        links = li.find_all(href=True)
        for link in links:
            if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
                item_link = link.get("href").strip()
                item_text = link.text.replace("View Position","").encode('utf-8').strip()
                # we use the same 'createCSV' object
                outfile.write_row(item_link, item_text)
```

**Most Recent Code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

class createCSV:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        try:
            self.csvFile = open(filename,'ab')
            headers = ['Link','Description']
            self.writer = csv.DictWriter(self.csvFile, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=headers)

            if os.stat(filename).st_size == 0:  # write header only once
                self.writer.writeheader()       
        except Exception, error:
            print error
    def write_row(self,link,desc):
        self.writer.writerow({'Link':link, 'Description':desc})
    def __del__(self):
        self.csvFile.close()

res = requests.get("http://deloittedk.easycruit.com/?_sp=136ecff9b65625bf.1504382903200&icid=top_").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")
outfile = createCSV('TotalOutput2.csv')

for link in links:
        item_link = link.get("href").strip()
        item_text = link.text.replace("View Position","").encode('utf-8').strip()
        outfile.write_row(item_link, item_text)

res = requests.get("http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/6257").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")
outfile = createCSV('TotalOutput2.csv')

for li in soup.find('ul', class_='list-articles list').find_all('li'):
    level = li.find_all('dd', {'class': 'author'})[1].get_text()
    if "Graduate" in level:
        links = li.find_all(href=True)
        for link in links:
            if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
                item_link = link.get("href").strip()
                item_text = link.text.replace("View Position","").encode('utf-8').strip()
                outfile.write_row(item_link, item_text)
```

Comment: It seems your question is about appending to CSV files. Is it possible to simplify your question by removing all references to web scraping, and by preparing smaller samples that illustrate the problem?

Comment: Hi Kos - thanks for the input. I did add it in because I thought it was relevant , but I'm quite new here so happy to follow your advice. What information is needed to answer this question?

Comment: Web scraping and writing CSVs are completely unrelated activities, but only one of them is relevant to the particular problem you're having.

Comment: I have tried to make it a bit easier to digest now - would you be able to help me answer the question?

Comment: if you run the same script multiple times, does it append to the file properly, or replace it?

Comment: Make sure that you close the file after appending the data. Also note that if the writes are concurrent it may not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution to this is to create a *class* to handle the *[`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)-appending* process. The class will be as follows:

```
import csv
import os

class createCSV:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        try:
            self.csvFile = open(filename,'ab')
            headers = ['Link','Description']
            self.writer = csv.DictWriter(self.csvFile, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=headers)

            if os.stat(filename).st_size == 0:  # write header only once
                self.writer.writeheader()       
        except Exception, error:
            print error

    def write_row(self,link,desc):
        self.writer.writerow({'Link':link, 'Description':desc})

    def __del__(self):
        self.csvFile.close()
```

As you can see we make use of the [`stat.ST_SIZE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.ST_SIZE) variable to be able not to write the *csv-header* every time we want to append a new item on the csv file.

---

**Update**

Now you can combine it with your scrapers like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

class createCSV:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        try:
            self.csvFile = open(filename,'ab')
            headers = ['Link','Description']
            self.writer = csv.DictWriter(self.csvFile, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=headers)

            if os.stat(filename).st_size == 0:  # write header only once
                self.writer.writeheader()       
        except Exception, error:
            print error

    def write_row(self,link,desc):
        self.writer.writerow({'Link':link, 'Description':desc})

    def __del__(self):
        self.csvFile.close()

res = requests.get("http://your_1st_url_here").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")

# here we create the "test.csv" which 
# we will use to append values to
outfile = createCSV('test.csv')

for link in links:
        item_link = link.get("href").strip()
        item_text = link.text.replace("View Position","").encode('utf-8').strip()
        # append values to "test.csv"
        outfile.write_row(item_link, item_text)

# Remember that for the second scraper to write on the same .csv file 
# as the first one, you need to use the same 'createCSV' object - which 
# in this case is the "outfile".


res = requests.get("http://your_2nd_url_here").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")

for li in soup.find('ul', class_='list-articles list').find_all('li'):
    level = li.find_all('dd', {'class': 'author'})[1].get_text()
    if "Graduate" in level:
        links = li.find_all(href=True)
        for link in links:
            if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
                item_link = link.get("href").strip()
                item_text = link.text.replace("View Position","").encode('utf-8').strip()
                # we use the same 'createCSV' object
                outfile.write_row(item_link, item_text)
```

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer coder! Will try this later today!

Comment: Hi Coder - your code runs fine individually. Prob a stupid question, but how do I combine them with the scrapers? (I have added them back into the question)

Comment: Hi Coder - when I try to run the entire code I get the following error: NameError: name 'outfile' is not defined

I have added in the code I tried to run at the top

Comment: @PalleBroe Hm.., that weird cause I just cp-pasted your code and worked fine for me - I got a proper csv

Comment: im using this version of Python: Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 - Would that impact the code?

Comment: @PalleBroe I also use python2.7.13 with LLVM 8.0 - but I don't think that the code is incompatible with your version. Check your identation(cause I use sublime sometimes that tends to be the issue) and if is possible could you post the exact error you get ? Also the code you are using is the exact 'Edited code' in your post - nothing else right ?

Comment: just tried using sublime. This is the error I get (using the code I have added in above): 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
>>>

Comment: Tried to troubleshoot that error, but can't seem to find the function that should be causing the issue. Do you have any idea @Coder?

Comment: @PalleBroe The error is related to `bs4` - it seems that when you apply `find_all` the object (`soup` or `li` in the above example) is None instead of `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>`. I couldn't reproduce the issue with my code from above, you must have missed sth in the scraping process. If I were in your case I would try to debug, use e.g. `print type(a_var_here)` to check if the variables are what you expect them to be :)

Comment: I tried all the functions and they work individually, however the error I'm getting now is:   File "<stdin>", line 10, in <module>
AttributeError: createCSV instance has no attribute 'write_row' - any input would be super valuable!

Comment: @PalleBroe The code still works for me, have you renamed `write_row` method to something else? Also have you initialized the "createCSV" instance correctly passing as parameter the name of the csv?

Comment: This is the weirdest thing ever - I just can't get it to work. I just tried to run through the entire code and also copy your code above and I keep on getting issues. I have added in the most recent code above - could you try and use that to see if you get any errors?

Comment: update. it runs! However two small issues - I only get the results from the first part of the code (deloitte) and the url link and the description are merged as one column instead of two. I have added in the code above. Any idea to the two issues?

Comment: @PalleBroe **1)** I successfully executed your code. Well first of all, my csv file had two columns - so maybe try to change the separator from tab to sth else?. **2)** If your code is formatted as in your post then you have an indentation error in the first `for link in links:` **3)** You don't need to re-initialize the 2nd `createCSV` instance - in other words delete the 2nd `outfile = createCSV('TotalOutput2.csv')`. Hope it runs at last :) !!!